# ngAnnotate EPERM (unable to write) after re-installing application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, annotations, gruntjs

I'm using ngBoilerplate as a base for my application.
ngbp is using ngAnnotate and grunt-ng-annotate to well, annotate the application.

Everything was working fine until I had to format my computer and re-install the application from my git account.

I've installed everything again using npm install, bower install & grunt install and everything does seem to be installed correctly, all the dependencies exists and all the routes are correct.

When I run 'grunt watch' the build process work correctly.
When I run 'grunt build' the build process fails on ngAnnotate, it stops on a different file everytime, so the issue is not related to the file displayed in error message

```
Running "ngAnnotate:compile" (ngAnnotate) task
Warning: Unable to write "build/src/app/somefile.js" file (Error code: EPERM). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

This is the ngAnnotate config (the editor removes some charts, see https://gist.github.com/orzilca/f8a7312587a710094342):

```
    ngAnnotate: {
        compile: {
            files: [
                {
                    src: [ 'app_files.js (trimmed, see the link above)' ],
                    cwd: 'build_dir',
                    dest: 'build_dir',
                    expand: true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

And this is the app_files.js array:

```
    app_files: {
        js: [ 'src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.spec.js', '!src/assets/**/*.js' ]
    }
```

The full grunt file is here:
https://gist.github.com/orzilca/f25206920943231e15fe

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Found a fix for this problem!**

Using `npm outdated` I've found out I'm using an outdated version of `ng-annotate` (0.8.0).
Updating to the latest stable version (0.10.0) seems to fix the problem.

The build process it not working flawlessly :)